# Cloud Storage API Client Library for Java: - 400 Bad Request : "error" : "unauthorized_client"

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client, http-status-code-400

i am trying to build a connector to download files from google cloud. for this i am using  Cloud Storage API Client Library for Java (v1beta2-rev23-1.17.0-rc)

1. I am using oAuth2.0 and followed steps mentioned in cloud console help.
2. Verified that i can access my bucket via gsutil and api explorer.
3. Downloaded the code from samples ,added my client_secrets.json and added a line to list   my buckets content.

i am getting error

> "400 Bad Request : "error" : "unauthorized_client"

and not able to download the files.

Code is

https://gist.github.com/yashk/9226613

```
        /**
     * Main class for the Cloud Storage API command line sample.
     * Demonstrates how to make an authenticated API call using OAuth 2 helper classes.
     */
    public class StorageSample {

      /**
       * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name is {@code null} or
       * blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
       */
      private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "MyCompnay/1.0";

      /** Directory to store user credentials. */
      private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
          new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/storage_sample");

      /**
       * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to make it a single
       * globally shared instance across your application.
       */
      private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

      /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
      private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

      /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
      private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
      private static Storage client;

      /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
      private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
        // load client secrets
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
            new InputStreamReader(StorageSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter") ||
            clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
          System.out.println(
              "Overwrite the src/main/resources/client_secrets.json file with the client secrets file "
              + "you downloaded from the Quickstart tool or manually enter your Client ID and Secret "
              + "from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=storage#project:<project_id> "
              + "into src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
          System.exit(1);
        }

        // Set up authorization code flow.
        // Ask for only the permissions you need. Asking for more permissions will
        // reduce the number of users who finish the process for giving you access
        // to their accounts. It will also increase the amount of effort you will
        // have to spend explaining to users what you are doing with their data.
        // Here we are listing all of the available scopes. You should remove scopes
        // that you are not actually using.
        Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
        scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
        scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_READ_ONLY);
        scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_READ_WRITE);

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes)
            .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
            .build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          // initialize the transport
          httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

          // initialize the data store factory
          dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

          // authorization
          Credential credential = authorize();
          // set up global Storage instance
          client = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

          client.objects().list("<bucket_id>").executeAndDownloadTo(System.out);

        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
          t.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }
 }
```

Error Log is
https://gist.github.com/yashk/9226613

```java
Feb 26, 2014 9:28:05 AM com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest execute
CONFIG: -------------- REQUEST  --------------
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.17.0-rc (gzip)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 208

Feb 26, 2014 9:28:05 AM com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest execute
CONFIG: curl -v --compressed -X POST -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -H 'User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.17.0-rc (gzip)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '@-' -- 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token' << $$$
Feb 26, 2014 9:28:05 AM com.google.api.client.util.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream close
CONFIG: Total: 208 bytes
Feb 26, 2014 9:28:05 AM com.google.api.client.util.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream close
CONFIG: grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<removed_for_sec>&client_id=<removed_for_sec>&client_secret=<removed_for_sec>
Feb 26, 2014 9:28:05 AM com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse <init>
CONFIG: -------------- RESPONSE --------------
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Server: GSE
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Wed, 26 Feb 2014 09:28:01 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json

Feb 26, 2014 9:28:05 AM com.google.api.client.util.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream close
CONFIG: Total: 37 bytes
Feb 26, 2014 9:28:05 AM com.google.api.client.util.LoggingByteArrayOutputStream close
CONFIG: {
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured this out with help of our google corporate contact -

in authorize method

instead of

```
return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
      }
```

use  your google account user name from the cloud console

```
return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("myemail@mycompany.com");
      }
```

after this change if you run the code , it will popup a browser window and ask you authorize
access to the project and bingo!